# Sidebar scrolls very fast using touchpad in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just downloaded vscode in my new laptop and it works great. The only problem is the scrolling speed in the sidebar and the intellisense scrollbar. Is it possible to reduce the speed of the scrolling in vscode? I reduced it in the editor using the `editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity` in the settings.json but that only works for the editor and not the sidebar.

I have included a gif screenshot of the sidebar, I was only moving the touchpad a little bit and it moves so fast for my eyes to keep up

Any help would be appreciated it

[image: vscode]

Answer (score 4):

Try one of these settings:

```
workbench.list.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity
workbench.list.fastScrollSensitivity
```

new in vscode 1.59.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Worked for me,
Go to **regedit** (open run(win+r) and type "regedit")
Then go to "**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad**"
Then search for **ScrollControl_Mode**
double click and change value from 0 to 1.
Click Ok and done